# Having multiple projects in tabs like Eclipse? [IntelliJ]

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

So I just moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ after doing some research. The only thing that I miss is that in Eclipse I can have multiple projects in different tabs and compare projects easily. But in IntelliJ I have to open a project in a new window. Isn't it possible to have all the projects in the tool window like eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse, you can open up two windows which point to the same project. I am not sure what you mean by opening multiple projects as tool windows to compare them easily. Can you post a snapshot ? If you are talking about maven projects, then multiple 'projects' can be opened in a single IntelliJ instance by opening them as modules.

Comment: Is this what you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects

Comment: There is a workaround solution. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects I'm doing the same. It worked for me really, but I get the dialog asking me for removing the imported modules because they are not in the maven structure. Also trying to solve this.

Answer (score 13):

No, it's not possible. Please vote for [this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6118). Note that you can add your multiple projects as modules to Intellij Idea project to be able to view them in a single frame.
BTW, there is a document intended to help users migrating from Eclipse to Idea - see [this FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html) - you may find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

**Using Maven:** a untested aproach could be to have a simple maven Project including the other Maven projects as its childs and then import the simple maven Project that only defines the others as childs (and yes - please vote for such standard features).