# Android Studio - How to open more than one projects in tabs as like Eclipse

Tags: android-studio

How can I open multiple projects in single window (in Tabs) in android studio as in Eclipse?. When I am going to make a new project, then new projects will be opened in a new window. I want to open the projects like Eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having multiple projects in tabs like Eclipse? \[IntelliJ\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350723/having-multiple-projects-in-tabs-like-eclipse-intellij)

Comment: And don't forget to accept if my answer works for your issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like the following ?

[image: Android Studio Settings]

Comment: But this close the current and open the new project. it doesn't add it as a second tab to the IDE. `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1`

Comment: @Dr.jacky hello bro, sorry I have not used this for a long time, so cannot answer you anymore

Comment: The solution is when the projects are open separately, through one of the windows, click on `Window` -> `Merge All Project Windows`