# Eclipse workspace equivalent in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, projects-and-solutions

It is said in [IntelliJ IDEA Q&A for Eclipse Users](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html) that Eclipse Workspace is equivalent to "project" in `IntelliJ` terms, while Eclipse's project is equivalent to IntelliJ's module.

But after I created a project `untitled` and then created module `untitled2` I got the following picture

[image]

I would think `untitled` is a project and `untitled2` is a module, but both has `src` subfolders and listed in

[image]

so, both are modules of different level. Is this correct?

Is it possible to create module `untitled3` at the same level as `untitled`?

How to create several modules of the same level without topmost one?

Comment: Also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects, answer from Shock_N745. While import Module select type as Eclipse

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to simulate the Eclipse workflow, you should create an empty project (~ workspace) first:

`New Project > Empty Project`

Now you can create separate modules (~ projects) to be shown exactly like you want:

[image]

You could also select `untitled2`, press <kbd>F6</kbd> (`Refactor > Move`) and move it one level up in your directory. While creating `untitled3` you can specify the folder for your module (use `IdeaProjects` instead of `untitled`).

Comment: You want to move it to the `IdeaProjects` directory, not the `untitled` directory (where `untitled2` already exists, hence the message). Remove `untitled` from the path in the text box.

Comment: Hmmm... This worked, thanks. But where is project represented in filesystem now? How `IntelliJ` can know the list of modules?

Comment: Your project modules are listed in `.idea/modules.xml`. Your `.idea` folder (similar to `.settings` in Eclipse) is either in `.../IdeaProjects/` or `.../IdeaProjects/untitled/`.

Comment: Hmmm... It was in `untitled`. So, despite the fact two modules are looking equivalent, only one of them is "tagged" with `.idea` folder... Ok, will dig more, thanks.

Comment: That's because `untitled` was the only module when you created your project. If you follow my "empty project" tip, you will see the `.idea` folder in your root directory and your modules (without `.idea`) in different subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

The workspace equivalent term refers to Project Window in intellij. It will consists of modules which are equivalent of individual projects in Eclipse.

**EDIT:** You can right click on `untitled` module and go to `Open Module Settings`. And select `Modules` in project settings. With `+` sign you can choose to create new module. This should create new module on same level as `untitled`

Answer (score 3):

All the information you need is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-modules.html). JetBrains has a wonderful guide called "Working with modules".

Answer (score 1):

Modules can be created on any level and any location, regardless the project location. You can safely remove the "parent" module.

Comment: And how to re-create it once deleted?

Comment: Just add a new module, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-modules.html

Comment: But how to ensure it is toplevel?

Comment: You create it in a folder which is neither a child nor a  parent folder of your other module.

Comment: But in my case `untitled` is in the parent folder of `untitled2`. Hence, once I delete `untitled` I will be unable to recreate it?

Comment: Removal of a module does not delete any of your files.