# IntelliJ add (local) project as dependency for another one

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, organization, projects

I'd like to work on two projects simultaneously. Project A is kind of the core of Project B, but also more general. As I want to work on both at the same time, but let them be distinct (Project A will be used for other Projects as well) I'm kind of struggling on how to setup Project A as a dependency of Project B while also maintaining the ability to edit Project A's files during working on Project B.

I assume the following folder setup:

> -projects
>
> -- A (Core)
>
> -- B (Special)

How can I add A into B?

**edit**: We are talking SBT/non-sbt and only local projects here. One project (the older one/dependency) doesn't use SBT, while the new one (dependent) should.

I just want both projects in the same window so I can add new classes to the core and edit stuff as well without having to recompile everything again and jumping between windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a single project with multiple modules. Also see this: [IntelliJ: Working on multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects/8774056#8774056)

Comment: But is this the right thing to do? Or should I (as mentioned in your link) open a project and "add to current project"?

Comment: The accepted answer says to use modules, like I said. The highest-voted answer allows you to have multiple projects in the same window - but it seems that internally Idea adds the new project as a module (see the project structure window). So if you use Maven, the highest-voted answer is nothing but an easy way to set up dependent modules from existing projects.

Comment: The accepted answer is a few years older than the newer one, which is why I asked ;) Also I do not use or plan to use maven with these projects.