# Can you have multiple projects in the sidebar in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, projects

In eclipse I had all of my projects located in the sidebar by default.

Here's what I have:

[image]

Here's what I would like:

[image]

I find it hard to believe that you can't have more than one project in your sidebar but I can't find away to add multiple projects.

Comment: In my experience it is better to have a separate window for each project like the default Intellij behaviour. It keeps searches and refactors localized.

Comment: There is a workaround [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7897

a plugin for intellij idea which will allow you to work on multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

@sai rao gutta has a neat suggestion here, I'll have to look at that plugin.

I recently made the switch from Eclipse to Idea and this was a stumbling block for me as well.  The way I came to understand the Idea paradigm was to consider an Idea Project similar to a Workspace in Eclipse, and a Module in Idea similar to a Project in Eclipse.

Some of the projects I work on are libraries (usually sandbox type projects) where I want to see instant use of Project A as a dependency on Project B without having to run builds and whatnot.  Or, sometime I just want to use Idea as I did Eclipse and just keep a few random projects available.  I created an Empty Project in Idea, then added Modules within.  The end result gave me the ability to sandbox a library project and a consuming project in one space in a simple way, as well as give me a space to work with whatever random projects I had in Eclipse.