# How to edit classes of a library from different project in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

How can I make changes to a library that exists as separate intellij project and is included as maven lib?

Project structure:

```
/IdeaProjects/mycommons/
/IdeaProjects/mycore/
```

mycore pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, if I have the `/mycore` project open, and go into a class from `mycommons`, there are two issues:
1. I only the the decompiled `.class` file. I would expect to see the real java file.
2. I cannot edit this file. If I want to change anything, I have to open the mycommons project in a different idea window.
3. If I run the `mycore` after changes in `mycommons`, those changes are not automatically picked up. I first have to run `mvn install` on the `mycommons`, then they are found in the core project.

Coming from `eclipse`, none of these points have been an issue. Eclipse just recognized that included libraries are themselves eclipse project. So I could edit them all in one window, and run the changes without having to mvn install the libraries on each change explicit.

How can I achieve the same behaviour in `Intellij IDEA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:
[IntelliJ: Working on multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects)

> In "Maven Projects" tab, just click the green "+" button and add any existing commons projects pom.xml.

They then appear inside the project workspace in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Have a single IntelliJ project with both modules (mycore and commons). Same as Eclipse would have a single workspace with them.

Comment: I want to share the commons among all future company projects. So I cannot group the commons lib.

Comment: @membersound I meant IntelliJ project and modules, that is distinct from Maven...

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you mean? Currently I have two normal intellij projects, which means: different workspaces. If I would now copy the commons lib from one workspace into the other, it would only be available inside this core workspace. But ideally I'd like it being available in *any* workspace/project.

Comment: You can use the same module in multiple IntelliJ IDEA projects, import the module from the same location via the existing .iml file in another projects, simple as that.