# IDEA ,how to put serveral mirco-service projects into one same windows

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I use Intellij-IDEA to code java, some sping mirco service projects,I want to put them into one idea window ,how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it possible.
I think you use maven for your spring projects. if my intuition is correct you should look at this post:
[IntelliJ: Working on multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects)

This is very helpful for me.