# Is there way in intellij to see all packages?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

is there way to see all packages that are in folder like in eclipse, but in intellij?
[image]

Comment: Looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40818540/8370915) is related to your question. Also, please, take a look at this [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html).

Comment: You did a great job at censoring your screenshot, except now it really doesn't show us what it is you want to be displayed, does it now?

Comment: @invzbl3 Your reference worked! that is the answer , add your post as answer and I will mark for upvote! Thanks

Comment: @Joachim Sauer as invzbl3 wrote, to see the projects, that all

Answer (score 1):

To see al packages in the project, switch to **Packages** view in Project tool window and enable **Flatten Packages** [viewing mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-viewing-modes.html):

[image]

See also [Migrate from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html) for more tips.

Comment: I want to see few projects, not the packages as the answer of 
invzbl3 so thank you for the help