# intellij dark theme colour scheme not working

Tags: intellij-idea

Per this screenshot, in intelliJ one dark mode, the source text isn't coloured:

[image: not coloured]

The colour scheme is not applied:

[image: colour scheme]

Comment: Is you file located under sources root and detected as java class?

Answer (score 0):

Per @y.bedrov the project structure was not setup.

[image]

Various Java projects had to be imported as modules like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31418879/1964277)